# Printing from a buffer using the read(2) function in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read in bits using the read function and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to printf the results using the buffer.

currently the code fragment is as follows

```
 char *infile = argv[1];
 char *ptr = buff;
 int fd = open(infile, O_RDONLY); /* read only */
 assert(fd > -1);
 char n;
 while((n = read(fd, ptr, SIZE)) > 0){ /*loops that reads the file                                until it returns empty */
   printf(ptr);
 }
```

Comment: This might crash, if you read a string like "%s" or any another sequence that will make printf look for more arguments. Use something like `printf("%s", ptr);`
Also, you must make sure your buffer is zero-terminated, else printf will read past its end.

Comment: Also, I have posted the above as a comment, because I can't give you a proper answer, since you haven't actually asked a question.

Answer (score 1):

The data read into `ptr` may contain `\0` bytes, format specifiers and is not necessarily `\0` terminated.  All good reasons not to use `printf(ptr)`.  Instead:

```
// char n;
ssize_t n;
while((n = read(fd, ptr, SIZE)) > 0) { 
  ssize_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf(" %02hhX", ptr[i]);
    // On older compilers use --> printf(" %02X", (unsigned) ptr[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that does the job for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE        1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *infile = "Text.txt";
    char ptrBuffer[SIZE];
    int fd = open(infile, O_RDONLY); /* read only */
    assert(fd > -1);
    int n;
    while((n = read(fd, ptrBuffer, SIZE)) > 0){ /*loops that reads the file                                until it returns empty */
        printf("%s", ptrBuffer);
        memset(ptrBuffer, 0, SIZE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can read file name as parameter.

Comment: OK. While running the edited program without a pointer (complete C noob at the moment), I don't get an actual integer value but symbols.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, can you attach your file? Also point out which integer is showing up symbols

Answer (score 0):

Even if `ptr` is a string, you need to use `printf("%s", ptr);`, not `printf(ptr);`

However, after you call

```
read(fd, ptr, SIZE)
```

`ptr` is rarely a string (strings need to be null-terminated). You need to use a loop and choose the format you need. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%02X ", *ptr);
```